# Is there a way to conditionally pass the functor as predicate to standard library algorithm?

Tags: c++, std

I have a call to `std::mismatch` with many arguments and based on some condition I need either to run standard version or version with my predicate.

Is there a way to avoid `std::mismatch` call duplication, somehow putting this condition to the place where the `some_functor` is passed?

Some kind of inline solution is preferable (short and straightforward).

Here is the fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9bb99aYbz).

Here is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct some_functor {
    bool is_5_met = false;

    bool operator ()(auto lhs, auto rhs) {
        if (is_5_met) {
            return false;
        }

        if (lhs == 5 || rhs == 5) {
            is_5_met = true;
        }

        return lhs == rhs;
    }
};

auto some_function(const std::vector<int>& data, long offset, bool cond) {
    return cond
        ? std::mismatch(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin() + offset, data.end(), some_functor()).first - data.begin() 
        : std::mismatch(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin() + offset, data.end()).first - data.begin();
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, };

    std::cout << "Without 5 as sentinel : " << some_function(data, 7, false) << "\n";
    std::cout << "With 5 as sentinel : " << some_function(data, 7, true) << "\n";
}
```

Of course, I can pass the condition variable to the functor and process there, but this will lead to excessive check on high frequency operation. The code is on the critical path and any such indirection hits.

I would like to have something like:

```
auto some_function(const std::vector<int>& data, long offset, bool cond) {
    return std::mismatch(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin() + offset, data.end(), cond ? some_functor() : AND-DEFAULT-COMPARISON-HERE).first - data.begin();
}
```

I want to avoid making polymorphic functors, as well. It would be nice to avoid making "trivial" functor, is possible.

With the latter I mean that I could possibly write lambda that will return conditionally one of two lambdas, mine and "trivial" with the `lhs == rhs` check only, but I still want to reuse build-in comparison rather than hope that compiler will inline mine and that it will work always as expected.

Comment: `std::mismatch(..., some_condition ? some_functor{} : std::equals{})`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I can't find such thing as `std::equals`. Can you, please pinpoint the documentation? Do you mean `std::equal` or `std::equal_to` ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The second two operands of the conditional operator need to have a common type

Comment: @Artyer, yes, that's why I am writing about possible options like polymorphic functors (or maybe static template-based polymorphic, if possible). But is there any way to avoid duplication here? Maybe in some different simple way?

Comment: @JaMiT, I know for sure that `{}` doesn't work as "omit this parameter", I used this just to explain what kind of code I want to have. Had I known the answer, I would have worded in better in syntax manner. I took `{}` for sake of explaining from default parameters of standard library templates, just a way to put there something.

Comment: @JaMiT, I've added the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9bb99aYbz). Can you, please, take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a common type to the algorithm invocation e.g.:

```cpp
using common_t = std::function<bool(int const&, int const&)>;

std::mismatch(
  data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin() + offset, data.end(), 
  cond ? common_t(some_functor{}) : common_t(std::equal_to<int>{})
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
).first - data.begin();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7xdc6KPxh)

Note this is one of many possibilities. Others include:

- Encapsulate the "if" in your function object's constructor.
- Use a factory method to return polymorphic objects where the variation is expressed as overriden `operator()(int const&, int const&)` (only consider if you need to scale the number of behaviors)
- Encapsulate the "if" in a comparator's template parameter and have specializations perform the different operations. Only consider if the condition is known at compile time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found that even type of `std::equal_to` is deducible, so `std::equal_to<>` works here. Are there any underwater stones with this approach?

Comment: On your suggested possibilities: (1) I can encapsulate `if` in functor object constructor, but how to use it avoiding this check in `operator()` which is called quite often? (2) This is what I wanted to avoid in my question with "*I want to avoid making polymorphic functors, as well*"; (3) No, condition is not known at compile time.

Comment: Wouldn't use `std::function` here lead to additional indirection? Am I correct that, anyway, even if it would, it would be once per `some_function` call, not once per `int` comparisons?

Comment: `std::function` uses type erasure. If your code is in a critical path you should benchmark the cost. It also requires the callable to be Copy Constructible.To avoid branching every time you call `operator()` the comparator can have two methods that express the `true` and `false` case; upon construction a "pointer to member function" member can be set to point to the desired method. This is also an indirection and you should examine if it's worth using over `std::function`. If condition is not known at compile time, it seems only something like `some_function` can avoid the extra indirection

Comment: @DamirTenishev btw "extra indirection" is also imposed by function pointers. Since the condition is not known at compile time and you don't want to use something like the ternary condition in `some_function` there is always going to be some indirection involved or extra function call

Comment: Yes, the code in on the critical path and preliminary measurement gives about 13% of performance degradation of one of the critical functions, so let's keep the question open.

Comment: Not just extra indirection, but that indirection makes it impossible to inline the comparison function where it's used. This will be a big performance killer.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Here's a bare-bone [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c18qsWzzh) where the indirection is dereferencing a pointer. Out of curiosity how much does this differ ?

Comment: @DamirTenishev -- don't be so quick to accept answers. Some folks won't bother reading a question with an accepted answer, so you run the risk of not getting a better answer. The usual guideline is wait a day or so.

Comment: I wrote the similar (except putting everything as member functions) [code](https://godbolt.org/z/8E5cY5rbr). The performance degradation is about 10.8%. After that tested with your approach, passing bool& to global functions, the same degradation  about 10.8%. So, indirection hits here.

Comment: @PeteBecker, you are right. I was so happy to see the "language" solution so I hasted to accept the answer. I was sure that this trick works only once on the high level function and couldn't affect the high frequency operation, so I never expected to have performance impact. I will follow next time.

Comment: @DamirTenishev How come your were asking "how not to call `if` on every `operator()` call" if you had implemented that? Do you use -O2 when compiling to enable optimizations? In the [Demo I showed you](https://godbolt.org/z/Gaoe75rve) `some_functor` does not even generate a symbol ... it's inlined. It's hard to believe the 10% or 13% difference, here's microsecond [Benchmark](https://godbolt.org/z/hTaf1rxeh) for 10M iterations. I'd answer your question but I doubt it would change your mind, I blame myself for wasting my time trying to help somebody

Comment: @DamirTenishev May have flunked the benchmark, it does [show](https://godbolt.org/z/37sE5EYbx) bigger differences on subsequent runs. In any case I never wrote it's an optimization, just answering the "how to do it" part, hence the "measure it" advice when asked about pitfalls

Comment: I can't see how could I upset you and making thinking that you wasted your time. I marked the answer as useful (upvoted) and said “Thank you so much!” as a first statement. I just recalled the “Accepted” mark hoping that, as *Pete Becker* said in his comment, somebody will be able to step in with better solution. So, as I wrote in my comments to *JaMiT*’s answer below, I am totally happy with your answer since it is a “natural” for language and answers exactly my question, with the only reservation that we both missed performance impact (to be continued...)

Comment: The performance requirements weren’t enough explicit in my original question, so this is my bad that we both missed the point. So, I am sorry, if I made this (my attitude to your answer) perceived in a wrong way. On your comment, for sure I use -O2 for Release version and I meant performance degradation for client code (which I can measure); since it does other actions, the numbers, of course, lower that “pure” impact. My point was that it is “sensible enough”. And, again, I still consider you answer better, but still waiting for alternatives, as *Pete Becker* suggested.

Comment: Funny thing about performance impact, even the solution from *JaMiT* below brings 10% decrease in my case for the code that using this function which I can't understand at all, since it must be inlined, definitely. Although 10% is not too much, the difference is strongly reproducible. Somehow original code works faster than all other cases. I don't think it worth further investigations, just funny thing.

Comment: Since we didn't get solutions which will be as language-oriented as yours and provide a way to avoid performance impact, I get the "accept" mark back for your answer. Just to care about future readers, it would be nice if you post some short note in your answer about possible performance impact of the on-fly condition processing so that people would be aware in case they have large data. Thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would add another layer of abstraction, breaking `some_function` into two pieces – one that calculates the ranges and one that decides which comparison to use (one responsibility per function). To put it another way, `some_function` handles the logic that is the same among the alternatives, while the new function, `check_mismatch`, handles the logic that is different.

```cpp
// The name of the iterator type is long enough to be distracting.
// Here's an alias to make reading the function signature easier.
using VecIter = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;

// Wrapper for std::mismatch that decides what comparison to use.
auto check_mismatch(const VecIter& begin1, const VecIter& end1,
                    const VecIter& begin2, const VecIter& end2, bool cond) {
    return cond
        ? std::mismatch(begin1, end1, begin2, end2, some_functor())
        : std::mismatch(begin1, end1, begin2, end2);
}

auto some_function(const std::vector<int>& data, long offset, bool cond) {
    return check_mismatch(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin() + offset, data.end(), cond)
        .first - data.begin();
}
```

---

> Is there a way to avoid `std::mismatch` call duplication,

Apparently (not the way I read it initially), this was supposed to mean "Is there a way, based on a runtime condition, to invoke one of two functions with different signatures without writing out two argument lists?" No, the language does not support this. Given functions

```cpp
void foo(char);
void bar(char, int);
```

There is no magic formulation that will let you write something like

```
(cond ? foo : bar)('c', cond ? 2 : <omitted>) // Not valid!
```

to choose between the two invocations. C++ is a strongly typed language, and that includes function types. You cannot play "mix and match" with function signatures. Each expression and sub-expression must have a known type. There are methods of type erasure available, but those add overhead, and the question states that extra overhead is to be avoided.

Having the same name (`std::mismatch`) for the two functions does not improve the situation. Details that would improve the situation (and that someone might overlook when looking at similar situations) include

- having the signatures be the same (and the names be different),
- knowing the the condition at compile time (and having the names be the same), or
- having one function with a default parameter instead of two function overloads.

Of course, the standard library cannot be changed to suit one's needs. So, in the question's scenario, there is no choice but to have somewhere a conditional that chooses between the two function signatures and lists arguments twice. I am not aware of something in the standard library that will hide this conditional without adding overhead.

Comment: Yes, this keeps the comparison functions simple and direct, so the compiler can in-line them inside `std::mismatch`. Too bad there's already an accepted answer. :-(

Comment: A new type alias and a new function which comes to 11 lines of code instead of 5? I am in twenty minds about this solution. Actually, this is just a "decoration" with function extraction. I am not sure that Occam's razor principle is not violated here. To put in a nutshell, it just moves the problem to another place, making code a little bit more readable with the price I am not sure worth it. This answer is mostly from "Code Review" category rather than the answer to the original question. I am not asking how to hide the problem, I am asking is there a way to solve it? Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @PeteBecker, we don't have the accepted answer yet. I still hope somebody could come with the solution or the answer why it is not possible at all, in the given conditions. I am not sure why you are so happy with a little decoration trick while the original question is not answered. The answer from *Nikos Athanasiou* have performance impacts, but it really answers the question, although lacks warnings on side effects. Current answer just says "let's make this garbage a little bit nicer". We call this "sweep the dust under the carpet". Problem is still here, but "nicely wrapped".

Comment: @DamirTenishev *"it just moves the problem to another place,"* -- This suggests that I was unable to identify what the problem is from the question. The problem as I understand it is that the calculations `data.begin() + offset` and `.first - data.begin()` are repeated in the calls to the two `std::mismatch` functions (hence could fall out of sync when the code is modified). My answer eliminates this duplication; it does not move the duplication to another place. If I can quote the question title, `check_mismatch` "conditionally [passes] the functor as predicate to standard library algorithm".

Comment: For me `std::mismatch(begin1, end1, begin2, end2` repeated twice is the same code duplication. I really appreciate the new code structure which reduces the chance of introducing a mistake while changing the original complex duplicated code in call to `std::mismatch` in `some_function` and I accept this as code review improvement, despite the fact of getting new alias and function in the "namespace" of which I am still concerned with, but the question is if it is still possible to avoid repeating `std::mismatch(begin1, end1, begin2, end2` at all. "No, because..." would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: I just was sure that this is easy doable in language and that's why I asked for. If this is impossible to do straightforward (like in a way suggested by *Nikos Athanasiou* - easy taken, but "poisoned" fruit), I'd like to know what exact logic of language I am trying to violate with this. Like "You are trying to use compile-time templates with run-time condition and compiler fails to generate such a code because...". To put in a nutshell, I am not looking for workarounds, I need a straightforward solution or understanding why it is not doable in language.

Comment: Just to explain my stand here better. Function extraction was one of the first my background ideas for solving this, but is was rejected in a way “Are there two usages for a new function? No? Let’s don’t swamp the “namespace” here, let’s see if this is doable in language”. And I decided to ask here. People always ask to keep my questions short without sections like “I could do this way, but don’t because of the following reasons” and here is the consequence. Anyway, the new type alias `VecIter` is not needed, `const auto&` could be used instead in the same way you used `auto` for return value.

Comment: @DamirTenishev *"despite the fact of getting new alias and function in the 'namespace' of which I am still concerned with,"* -- I would appreciate it if you would stop nitpicking my choice of coding style. Whether you define an alias or not is up to you. I chose a style that I believe will be more understandable to future readers with the same question. You've demonstrated that you know how to eliminate the alias in your own code, and this consideration is tangential to the answer, so why are you so hung up on it?

Comment: @DamirTenishev *"I am not looking for workarounds, I need a straightforward solution or understanding why it is not doable in language."* -- In my view, I gave a solution. I don't grasp where you are drawing the line between "workaround" and "solution". If you don't like my approach, that's fine with me. My answer is not really for you anyway, but for the people in the future who come here with the same question.

Comment: @JaMiT, as I stated in my initial comment, I am thankful for your answer. Please, don't get me wrong, I still consider it very valuable and helpful; it really helps to make the code more professional and avoid mess in the place of the call. So, your answer helps to solidify golden rule from *Butler Lampson* "*All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection*" in practice. My only point that I am looking for language-specific inline solution like *Nikos Athanasiou* provided. Sorry for being too persistent and maybe, emotional here.

Comment: @JaMiT, just to solidify your answer, what is the real reason to introduce `VecIter` type alias instead of using `const auto&` or implementing this as a template?

Comment: @DamirTenishev *"what is the real reason to introduce `VecIter` type alias instead of using `const auto&` or implementing this as a template?"* -- The real reason is what I stated in an earlier comment: to make the code more understandable. Use of `auto` obscures what the type is intended to be (especially bad in an explanation/answer), and a template increases code complexity. So I took my draft that had started with `template <class Iter>`, removed the `template` part and added a type alias. Easier to read.

Comment: @JaMiT, thank you for the explanations. I feel the same, especially when make `auto` a return type; still accustomed to self-documenting (and documentation, as well), when the type documents the returning value. This makes special point with returning values for me, since functions often do one thing and return another (like `std::unique`). When I do this, I still in two minds if this is old-school (type-centric) or really beneficial. The other end of stick is length of code and generalization. Anyway, I get your point and don't argue, just thinking aloud.