# Is there std algorithm or their combination to find the longest sequences of repeating values in a sorted array?

Tags: c++, search, sequence, std

**Functional specification**

In a sorted array (or vector) find the longest sequences of repeated values. The size of array is expected to be relatively large (up to a million of entries).

Please see the fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WGEb8nPce).

*Reservation*

Just to avoid the first optimization suggestion: actual code uses my implementation of [Incremental upper bound in sorted range](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289146/incremental-upper-bound-in-sorted-range/) instead of `std::upper_bound`; just don't want to overcomplicate things here.

**Question**

Is there a way to express this in terms of C++ Standard Library algorithms using one (or a simple combination of them) to avoid reinventing the wheel? Something like simple one-line solution.

I really don’t like this code because of two loops with two passes and the ugly if-else-if, but I don’t see a way to improve it easily.

I still hope some `std` algorithm or their combination could do this work much simpler.

*Since many people have focused on the code, please note that it is provided only to explain in code what I want to have in functional specification. Don't focus much on it. And if you are ready to suggest improvements, please note that performance if not a key, but matters; so, please, don't suggest solutions with collecting large amount of data in maps or other dynamic structures. My question only about simple one-line solution existence.*

**The code**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::pair<std::vector<size_t>,size_t> get_longest_ranges(auto first, auto last)
{
    ptrdiff_t max_range = 0;
    size_t amount_of_ranges = 0;
    auto it = first;

    while (it != last) {
        auto it_end = std::upper_bound(it, last, *it);

        if (max_range == it_end - it) {
            ++amount_of_ranges;
        } else if (max_range < it_end - it) {
            max_range = it_end - it;
            amount_of_ranges = 1;
        }

        it = it_end;
    }

    std::vector<size_t> ranges;
    ranges.reserve(amount_of_ranges);

    it = first;
    while (it != last) {
        auto it_end = std::upper_bound(it, last, *it);

        if (it_end - it == max_range) {
            ranges.push_back(it-first);
        }

        it = it_end;
    }

    return { ranges,  max_range };
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
    auto [starts, length] = get_longest_ranges(v.begin(),v.end());

    std::cout << "Max equal elements range length = " << length;

    for (auto start : starts) {
        std::cout << "\nAt position: " << start << " Values: ";
        for (size_t i = start; i < start + length; i++) {
            std::cout << v[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

**The expected result**

For the code above the expected result is:

> Max equal elements range length = 4
>
> At position: 3 Values: 2 2 2 2
>
> At position: 15 Values: 7 7 7 7

Comment: Why "generic" when you are looking for sequences in a vector of integers? What "generic" do you seek?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, it comes back and forth again and again. :) When I simplify my question is exact type people scream "where are templates, newbie!"; when I put templates people say "I decided to skip this question because it touches too hard template topics". Balance is hard. Can you please, close eyes on details and see to in "in generic way?"? I really don't know how to balance better here. Again, how using a specific type in the code is in your way to get the idea and recommend the algorithm?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, when I don't ask, people start screaming "Why don't you ask and learn and reinvent wheels"? When I ask people start long lectures about libraries :). I don't solve puzzles, this code is from real project where I really need it and in the project it is more complicated, based on suffix arrays, strings and some levels of generalization and indirection of data. I just simplified it to explain what exactly I am trying to achieve as *I am always asked by people on SO*. What is wrong here with this question?

Comment: when someone comments on your quesiton "where are templates, newbie!" you can ignore them, because its not a comment that should be taken serious.

Comment: "generic" can mean anything. If you cannot tell what you mean, I cannot either. It could be for other containers for other element types or for something else entierly.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, well, wording is always hard. Let's remove this statement (updated the question) and focus on the question itself, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm that comes in handy here is `std::equal_range`.

Note that you do not need to pass the input vector twice. One pass is sufficient to find all subsequences of longest size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main (){
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
    auto begin = v.begin();
    auto end = v.end();
    int longest = 0;
    auto longestit = begin;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> m;
    while (begin != v.end()) {
        auto res = std::equal_range(begin,end,*begin);
        int size = std::distance(res.first,res.second);        
        if (size > longest) {
            longest = size;
            m.clear();
            m.push_back(res.first);
        } else if (size == longest) {
            m.push_back(res.first);
        }
        begin = res.second;
    }
    std::cout << longest << "\n";
    for (const auto& v : m){ std::cout << *v << " "; }
}
```

The if-else is just the minimum needed to find the maxium while iterating and keeping track of all max elements. The rest is standard algorithms as requested.

One could argue that this would be a misuse of `std::equal_range`, because the code isnt actually using its full capabilities, while `std::find` or others could do the job as well. However, remember that many algorithms be customized to a point where their name becomes misleading and this isnt the case here. I think here `std::equal_range` explains quite well what the loop body is doing here.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be much better than my initial code with only one reservation; my initial code allowed me to reserve memory for the resulting vector, knowing exactly its size and avoiding reallocation while it grows. Let me check the impact on performance/memory fragmentation on real project before I accept the answer. With `std` algorithm(s) I mean something simple like when people answer "use alg1(alg2(data),pred)"; I mean, very simple solution I am missing; so I get your answer as "no such simple one-line solutions in `std`".

Comment: @DamirTenishev if you expect to find a stdandard algorithm that lets you solve any specific problem in one line of code, then imho you misunderstand standard algorithms.

Comment: @DamirTenishev btw basing whether you accept the answer on some metrics in a project that only you know is a) not fair b) not useful to anybody but you. Remember that questions and answers are supposed to be useful for future readers not only for you. Just saying

Comment: My understanding of `std` is a set of building blocks to be combined to get the solution in fast and straightforward way. Is it wrong understanding? I have a lot of code where very complex problems are solved with couple of lines of `std`, ranges,  views, projections and predicates. Recent ranges/views additions allowed to collapse 10-20 lines of code to 2-3 lines of pipes. I mean that I saw tons of such implementations and just wanted to double check that I haven't missed something in this case. Is this wrong?

Comment: On the accepting. I see where you coming from, but just had bad experience with being haste here (see the [Is there a way to conditionally pass the functor as predicate to standard library algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77937376/is-there-a-way-to-conditionally-pass-the-functor-as-predicate-to-standard-librar) ) and all long story about premature accepting the answer and reaction from people there. I won't base on my project data; if I see the performance issue, I will share the demo to discuss this. I just need more information before accepting based on the example on the link

Comment: @DamirTenishev cramping too much into a single line just for the sake of less lines of code, is not desirable imho. If you have something that can be expressed in a single line, sure, go for it. If it is more complex, it deserves more lines. Sure this argument depends on what the language has to offer, how it allows to express stuff, and I am not familiar with the ranges library. But insisting on "do it in one line" imho misses the point, because less lines of code is not always simpler or more expressive code

Comment: I totally agree with you here. My point is just learning the `std` to avoid inventing wheels and writing long code. I saw "bad" (long and "duplicating" in this case) code which is the only part of the 120 lines function which is really hard to grasp. I am working on simplifying it and this was the first stop I paid attention to. Taking into account that I am still not a big fun of "overdoing" method extraction (don't want to end up with hundreds of functions in the scope), the first way it to express simpler and shorter. Anyway, I agree, that "simpler" is key, not "shorter".

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai *many algorithms be customized to a point where their name becomes misleading* -- One such classic case is `std::adjacent_find`, where you use it to do a pair-wise loop, and not really use it to search for anything.

Comment: One last reservation since you started your answer with explicit mentioning of usage `std::equal_range` instead of `std::upper_bound` used in mine code. Actually you don't need `std::equal_range` here, this is excessive. The only place where you use `res.first` is for calculating the `size`, but here it always equal to `begin`; so you need only `res.second` which is `std::upper_bound`. Faster and comes from the original code. Thank you for your help here!